# Unity3d handling multiple Webclient.DownloadAsync in a nice way

Tags: multithreading, unity-game-engine, thread-safety, httpwebrequest

I am writing a managed Unity3d plugin which handles some web requests, registration and downloading content from the web. I am using the .Net WebClient class and the corresponding Async calls for down/uploading content in a separate thread to avoid laggy UI.

I am now trying to find an easy way to retrieve the callbacks from those async calls on the "unity3d side". Something like the follwing line of code does not work, obviously:

```
MyManagedPlugin.RequestDataAsync(Callback);
```

I also would like to avoid any thread specific code on the unity3d side (meaning in the scripts) so that all the async calls are encapsulated in the managed plugin. I am not sure if that is possible at all since there need to be some kind of polling mechanism to on the main thread (unit3d) to check if a thread is done right?

Comment: The `UnityEngine.WWW` class is already asynchronous, but with an `yield` interface instead of new style .NETish `async`. Don't see your point.

Comment: well WWW is asynchronous but does run in its own thread. I also want to have different task run in different threads